# Relational algebra for one-to-many relations

Tags: relational-algebra

Suppose I have the following relations:

```
Academic(academicID (PK), forename, surname, room)
Contact (contactID (PK), forename, surname, phone, academicNO (FK))
```

I am using Java & I want to understand the use of the notation.

`Π( relation, attr1, ... attrn )` means project the n attributes out of the relation.
`σ( relation, condition)` means select the rows which match the condition.
`⊗(relation1,attr1,relation2,attr2)` means join the two relations on the named attributes.
`relation1 – relation2` is the difference between two relations.
`relation1 ÷ relation2` divides one relation by another.

Examples I have seen use three tables. I want to know the logic when only two tables are involved (academic and contact) as opposed to three (academic, contact, owns).

I am using this structure:

```
LessNumVac = Π( σ( job, vacancies < 2 ), type )
AllTypes = Π( job, type )
AllTypes – LessNumVac
```

How do I construct the algebra for:

> List the names of all contacts owned by academic "John"

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give operator definitions & your reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> List the names of all contacts who is owned by academic "John".

For that, you would join the `Academic` and `Conctact` relations, filter for John, and project the name attributes. For efficiency, select John before joining:

π<sub>forename, surename</sub> (Contact ⋈<sub>academicNO = academicID</sub> (π<sub>academicID</sub> (σ<sub>forename = "John"</sub> Academic))))

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend your operations set with `natural join ⋈`, `Left outer join ⟕` and/or `Right outer join ⟖` to show joins.

There is a great Wikipedia article about [Relational Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra). You should definitely read that one!